# Prevent duplicate rows from 2 crons job

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I have a script that inserts into a database, the script is called from 2 cron jobs simultaneously so in many cases I can have the same data at the same time ( hour,minute,second ).
Actually I don't have control on the cron jobs but I have it on the script.
So is that any way to prevent duplicating rows ?

code :

```
function checkDuplicate($email) {
    $return = 0;
    if($email != "" ){
        $sql = "SELECT d.id_data as nbre FROM data d WHERE  d.email = '" . $email . "' ";
        $nbreEmails = $db->run($sql);
        $return = (sizeof($nbreEmails) > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return $return;
}

if(!checkDuplicate($email)){
    $insert = array(
       "id_client" => $id_client,
       "email" => $email,
       "valide" => 1,
       "stat" => "valide",
       "date_insert" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
       "date_refus" => null
    );

    $db->insert("data", $insert);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you may check by db time and other columns and insert row time and other columns, if both are same then you can stop inserting new data.

Comment: create a unique index

Comment: can't do that coz it's at the same moment, i already check if the data exist and it returns false.

Comment: show your code and your DB schema.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg plz see the edit .

Comment: @e4c5 can't add index coz it may have the same email but for different client.

Comment: add unique index for id_client-email

Comment: not certain what your $db is, but you should force a commit immediately after the insert. Nothing is ever 'simultaneous', and in all likelihood your insert on one thread is not committed when the `checkDuplicate` is invoked on the other thread. Whatever your $db is, you should switch to a PDO access object to have some protection against nefarious SQL injections. The way you store time garanties you will have the `appearance` of simultaneity, but is is just an illusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your timestamp field as an unique.

If you can't set it, or there is more complicated conditions that should cofirm that script1 & script2 will never do insert (or whatever with this table) in the same time, you should use lock tables, I.e.:

```
// not sure waht do you use as $db
$db->execute('LOCK TABLES data WRITE;');
...// inserts
$db->execute('UNLOCK TABLES;');
```

or use transactions (for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html))

Suggest you to use PDO ([PDO::beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php))

Or update your post with framework name that you use, most of them should have a way to do it.

Comment: I dont think the `none` framework supports ACID transactions.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, sure you're right, ACID is not complete even for the MySQL itself, but for the inserts it will work, at least with PDO.